# Directing urls with no extension to the root

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I currently have the htaccess file set so that if someone types `www.example.co.uk/index.php` it redirects to `www.example.co.uk/`

However, if someone types `www.example.co.uk/index`, the URL stays as `www.example.co.uk/index`

Is there a way that I can make this also redirect to the root and hide the `/index` part?

htaccess code is currently as follows (I have left out most of the 301 redirects)

```
ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.w-co\.co.uk$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.w-co.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]


Options +FollowSymLinks 
# Redirect index in any directory to root of that directory
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index\.[^\ ]*\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.(php|html?)$ http://www.w-co.co.uk/$1? [R=301,L]

AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/webm .webm

Redirect 301 /%20built-up-lettering.php  http://www.w-co.co.uk/built-up-lettering.php
Redirect 301 /&amp;quot;&amp;gt;light http://www.w-co.co.uk/light_boxes.php
```

Comment: Please post your current .htaccess file.  It's important to post _all_ of it, as it is highly order dependent.

Comment: My current htaccess file is as follows (There are a lot more 301 redirects). ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.w-co\.co.uk$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.w-co.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index\.[^\ ]*\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.(php|html?)$ http://www.w-co.co.uk/$1? [R=301,L]

AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/webm .webm

Redirect 301 /%20built-up-lettering.php  http://www.w-co.co.uk/built-up-lettering.php

Comment: Oh, please edit your question above to include the htaccess contents, rather than here in comments. Highlight all the lines and click the `{}` editor toolbar button or `ctl-k` to make it into a code block.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I have edited the original post now.

Answer (score 0):

Add a rewrite rule to your `.htaccess` for:

```
^www.example.co.uk/index$
```

And that should cover it.

Comment: I tried adding that rewrite rule but unfortunately it caused an internal server error.

Comment: I still haven't managed to work out how to do this. Anyone have any ideas?